# Python3 C extension module: SystemError: Type does not define the tp_name field

Tags: c, python-3.x, linux, i2c

I am working on the migration of the C extension module of this repository [Python2 sensor driver](https://github.com/lexruee/am2315) from python 2 to python 3. I used the help under [Migrating C extensions](http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html) and saved the changes in a fork here [Python3 fork](https://github.com/brenkem/am2315). But when I build && install the project and run the test under [am2315/examples/test_1.py](https://github.com/brenkem/am2315/blob/master/examples/test_1.py) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/git/am2315/examples/test_1.py", line 2, in <module>
from tentacle_pi.AM2315 import AM2315
SystemError: Type does not define the tp_name field.
```

But the tp_name is defined here [am2315/src/am2315_ext.c](https://github.com/brenkem/am2315/blob/00d136c04fb829c061b940b2c65fb8c306f6b0a3/src/am2315_ext.c#L98). What needs to be changed to define the tp_name field?

Comment: your struct is wrong, see the [newest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#examples), it's better to use named struct members initialization to avoid such errors.

Comment: Thanks @ahmed-aek for the tip. I fixed the struct according the docs here [commit](https://github.com/brenkem/am2315/commit/cf5cf75cb1fd24e16b5ac4ceee5133e787b6cfdf). I also added the methods, but it does not work to find them. So I get a attribute error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/git/am2315/examples/test_1.py", line 7, in <module>
    temperature, humidity, crc_check = am.sense()
                                       ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'tentacle_pi.AM2315' object has no attribute 'sense'
`

Comment: the methods struct pointer should be in the `tp_methods`, in the class struct.

Comment: Indeed. A bit confusing to see it different in some examples, But is is working with the tp_methods definition. **Case closed. Thanks.**